# Android - How to properly query online database using logins and passwords?

Tags: java, php, android, database

For my Android apps, I typically query databases by sending GET or POST parameters to various PHP script URLs, which in turn spit out xml or json that I parse in my app.

But if I have a database with personal protected information in it that users would normally use a login/password to access, what is the best approach to querying this information from the app? My above method would work, but I'd probably need to send the user's login/pass as GET or POST parameters... but that seems like a bad idea...

Typically with a web app, a user logs in and then PHP sessions are used from that point on. Not sure how to approach this type of thing with an Android app though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think authentication is separate for android applications the connect to web services.

You'd replicate the same authentication mechanism that you use in your web service on the android. That is to say, if you use http authentication in your web service (which transmits clear text passwords),  you'd replicate http authentication on the android. If you do not want to pass clear text credentials through the wire, you'd first have to implement something more secure (https) in your web service first.

For my project, I pass the clear text credentials using a POST request to the server. Browsers also transmit clear text passwords. After authentication, the service sends back a token (a database user id in a trivial case) which must be included in all future requests that requires a user to be logged in.

When storing the login id & password into preferences, I use sha1 to hash it first. That does mean that next time around, my web service is passed the hashed credentials and must know how to deal with it.

This mechanism is simple and suffices for my need. I cannot really afford, for this project, something like https.

Comment: If you store, and pass the password as a hash.. wouldn't hashing the password be useless? Since you don't need the password anyway, i mean.